# Notepad++, Posix regex, and a URL (regex to get domain)

Tags: regex, url, notepad++, posix, fqdn

I have a list of domains, hosts, and URLs.  I would like to use either Notepad++'s extended or regex search to go through my list and give me just the domain.  My list looks like:

```
fonts.googleapis.com 
fonts.gstatic.com 
http://s3.amazonaws.com/
*.adnxs.com
*.On24.com
ssl.gstatic.com
http://www.pinterest.com
```

What I'd like to end up with is a list of just the domain names such as:

```
googleapis.com
gstatic.com
```

Could someone provide a regex that would allow me to take a URL/FQDN and end up with just the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.*\.(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)
```

You can use this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rC2mH4/6

P.S This will fail in case of domains like `something.com.au` .They will have to handled separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following regex in replace dialog of notepad++ (uncheck ". matches newline").
Find: `^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.[^./\r\n ]+)[ /]*$`
Replace with: `\1`

"Replace All" should produce the list (tested with Npp version 7.6.6):

```
googleapis.com
gstatic.com
amazonaws.com
adnxs.com
On24.com
gstatic.com
pinterest.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ use replace feature and use regex like this for find pattern:

```
^[^.]*\.
```

Replace by empty string.